# Can't select bone while weight painting after parenting an object to a specific bone in the armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I've tried parenting a backpack to a bone before and after parenting the rest of the character to  the armature with automatic weights. In both cases, this seams to turn off my ability to select a bone in weight painting mode with ctrl. lmb.I don't have Paint Mask or Vertex Select on, but I do use Vertex Select while weight painting usually. I'm in the latest build of Blender 4.02. I'd be ridiculously grateful for some help on this'n.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Woops! They changed the hotkey in Blender 4.x.  It's now <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>. Never mind...

Comment: Shift LMB should work as well